# How to static link zmq and protobuf in a shared library?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, protocol-buffers, zeromq, static-linking

My goal is to create a shared library that includes statically protobuf and zeromq libraries. They should be inside `libfoo.so`

I have `foo.cpp`

```cpp
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string.h>
#include "messages.pb.h"
#include "foo.h"

int fooFunction(){ 
// Use zmq and protobuf
}
```

To compile I use the following commands

`c++ -Wall -fPIC -c foo.cpp -o foo.o`

`c++ -fPIC -c messages.pb.cc -o messages.o`

`c++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so  foo.o messages.o /usr/lib/libprotobuf.a /usr/local/lib/libzmq.a`

This error appears:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(src_libzmq_la-ctx.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

I tried to recompile zmq with this flags `./configure --enable-static --disable-shared` but nothing happend.`

I tried to link with the following command but didn't solve my problem: `c++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so  foo.o messages.o -Bstatic -lprotobuf -lzmq`

Comment: I think you need to compile libprotobuf and libzmq with `-fPIC` or `-fPIE` as well.

Comment: @botje I tried to compile libzmq with -fPIC following [this link](https://github.com/zeromq/zyre/issues/609) but didin't solve the problem

Comment: Did you remove any built files first? Did you make sure to link against the newly generated libzmq?

Comment: @botje yes I remove every libzmq file before recompiling, I find them using `find / -name "*libzmq*"`